# Decryption: length of the data to decrypt is invalid

Tags: vb.net, encryption

Trying to decrypt data but there is an error showing up only when using a long email that converts to 75 bits any other email used runs fine

```
Public Function DecryptData(
       ByVal encryptedtext As String) As String
       If String.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedtext) Then
           Return ""
       End If

        Convert the encrypted text string to a byte array. 
       Dim encryptedBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedtext)

       ' Create the stream. 
       Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
       ' Create the decoder to write to the stream. 
       Dim decStream As New CryptoStream(ms,
               TripleDes.CreateDecryptor(),
               System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

       ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.

       decStream.Write(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length)
```

ERROR OCCURS AT FLUSHFINAL BLOCK WHEN HAVING A STRING INTO 75 BYTES WITH ERROR :length of the data to decrypt is invalid

```
        decStream.FlushFinalBlock()

        ' Convert the plaintext stream to a string. 
        Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray)
    End Function
```

Comment: If the encryption code fails to flush the final block correctly then this can happen.

Comment: Please create an [mcve] which includes the encryption code inputs as well as expected outputs.

Comment: i use this for sending statements to clients but when the sender email is long then the error occurs